# Get Facebook leads by using API

Tags: php, api, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I got an API to download Facebook leads in excel format shown like below,
`https://www.facebook.com/ads/lead_gen/export_csv/?id=XXXXXXXXXX&type=form`,

How can I download this excel sheet into my server by using PHP curl code ?

I tried:

```
$output_filename = "test.csv";
                    $host = "https://www.facebook.com/ads/lead_gen/export_csv/?id=XXXXXXXXXXX&type=form";
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.facebook.com");
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                    $result = curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                    print_r($result);
                    $fp = fopen($output_filename, 'w');
                    fwrite($fp, $result);
                    fclose($fp);
```

when I run this code like `https://Ip/facebook/facebook.php`,I am getting below response.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Oqf.png)

Can any one help on it please ?

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: could any one help on it please ?

Comment: To use the API, I bet you need to register and use credentials.

Comment: @MarkusZeller thanks for response,  I created Facebook app in developer tool and based on it  I have created access token and I have followed this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54877083/php-curl-to-verify-facebook-api-login-access-token-on-server I am getting ```login valid``` I have run that code in that condition but same error which I posted in question

Comment: The error in the browser is irrelevant. Is there any curl error?

Comment: @MarkusZeller thank for your replay ,I can't see any error in my curl and i am using chrome updated browser